# What does "error: redefinition" mean? and how do i fix it?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I got this error twice. it says "error: redefinition of '-[SampleTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the method  '-[SampleTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]' twice in your project (file) and the compiler can't decide which one to pick.